# Use window.crypto in nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am trying to use the `window.crypto.getRandomValues` method in a nodejs script. From my understanding there is no `window` element when I run a simple code like this in node:

```
var array = new Uint32Array(10);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
```

Which is why I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

How can I use this method in my code?

Thanks

Comment: What about crypto.subtle.generateKey(...)?

Comment: In "window" is only used in web development Javascript, not node.js. Use globalThis to replace window.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html) module instead. It provides both a [`crypto.randomBytes()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) as well as a [`crypto.pseudoRandomBytes()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pseudorandombytes_size_callback).

However it should be noted that these methods give you a Buffer object, you cannot pass in a Uint32Array or similar, so the API is a bit different.

Comment: ok thanks. How can I turn the buffer object returned as a simple 256-bit number?

Comment: You'd have to use some javascript big number/integer library to convert the bytes to a number that large.

Comment: Note that as of version 7.10.0 of Node, there is a [`crypto.randomFillSync()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomfillsync_buffer_offset_size) function in NodeJS which allows you to pass a `TypedArray`.

Answer (score 23):

```js
const crypto = require('crypto').webcrypto;

let a = new Uint8Array(24);
console.log(crypto.getRandomValues(a));
```

This works almost exactly like the one in the browser, by adding `webcrypto` to the end of `requrie('crypto');`.

Comment: Should note that crypto.webcrypto is only available in Node.js 15.0.0+. LTS versions do not yet support it.

Comment: Node 16 is LTS now and this makes it a great answer!

Comment: Typescript makes using this harder than expected https://github.com/denoland/node_deno_shims/issues/56 ... to bypass I used `const crypto = webcrypto as any`

Answer (score 11):

You can use this module which is the same as the window element: [get-random-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-random-values)

Install it:

```
npm install get-random-values --save
```

Use it:

```
var getRandomValues = require('get-random-values');

var array = new Uint32Array(10);
getRandomValues(array);
```

Comment: This isn't the same as the window element, this use nodejs crypto

Comment: TypeError: expected Uint8Array

Comment: This should be the correct answer, with a simple addition, this can behave the same as the browser version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use it in Node 16 with TypeScript. I'm hijacking the web types and overriding the @types/node type, which are missing webcrypto.

```
import { webcrypto } from 'crypto'
const crypto = webcrypto as unknown as Crypto
const random = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(24))
```

This sandbox will work in Node 16, but stackblitz won't release node 16 for another couple months. https://stackblitz.com/edit/koa-starter-wychx9?file=package.json

Issue: github.com/denoland/node_deno_shims/issues/56

Answer (score 2):

As of Node.js v19.0.0 (noted in this changelog: https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v19.0.0) `globalThis.crypto` in Node.js is now the same as `webcrypto` imported from `'crypto'`:

So you can now do this and get the same (random) result in Node.js as in the browser:

```js
globalThis.crypto.getRandomValues
```

Note the usage of `globalThis` rather than `window`. See docs here if needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I solved it this way

```
import * as crypto from 'node:crypto'

export function randomChar() {
  return crypto.webcrypto.getRandomValues(new BigUint64Array(1))[0].toString(36)
}
```

Reference:
[How to use getRandomValues() in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088396/how-to-use-getrandomvalues-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js 19 you can just use it (without `window.`)

```js
const array = new Uint32Array(10);
crypto.getRandomValues(array);
```