# JS generate random boolean

Tags: javascript, random, boolean

Simple question, but I'm interested in the nuances here.

I'm generating random booleans using the following method I came up with myself:

```
const rand = Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()));
```

Whenever `random()` shows up, it seems there's always a pitfall - it's not truly random, it's compromised by something or other, etc.  So, I'd like to know:

a) Is the above the best-practice way to do it?

b) Am I overthinking things?

c) Am I underthinking things?

d) Is there a better/faster/elegant-er way I don't know of?

(Also somewhat interested if B and C are mutually exclusive.)

*Update*

If it makes a difference, I'm using this for movement of an AI character.

Comment: `const rand = Math.random() < 0.5` is equivalent and simpler.

Comment: Nothing is actually random, the goal is to get as close to random as possible.

Comment: And if you have a 50/50 chance,`math.random` should be plenty. Just use milliseconds for your seed.

Comment: I think it's pretty random the time one visits a website :D so I had this idea... `Boolean(+Date.now()%2)`

Comment: With lodash - `!!_.random(1)`

Answer (score 659, accepted):

You can compare `Math.random()` to `0.5` directly, as the range of `Math.random()` is `[0, 1)` (this means 'in the range 0 to 1 including 0, but not 1'). You can divide the range into `[0, 0.5)` and `[0.5, 1)`.

```
var random_boolean = Math.random() < 0.5;
```

```js
// Example
console.log(Math.random() < 0.1); //10% probability of getting true
console.log(Math.random() < 0.4); //40% probability of getting true
console.log(Math.random() < 0.5); //50% probability of getting true
console.log(Math.random() < 0.8); //80% probability of getting true
console.log(Math.random() < 0.9); //90% probability of getting true
```

Comment: I like this one solution, as it allows you to tweak the probability of true/false

Comment: if you change the number 0.5 to 0.9 for instance, does this increase the probability of false, and how?

Comment: if you change it from 0.5 to 0.9. Then, the probability is likely to be changed. I think you can try it with a large number of random loop, like 10000 iterations.

Comment: For modern JavaScript you should use `let` i.e. `let randomBool = Math.random() >= 0.5;`

Comment: Why not use just `<` instead of `>=`? `Math.random() < 0.5` is exclusive of 0.5 for the low half and exclusive of 1 for the high half- so it's still exactly a 50% chance. Plus, it's shorter. And in my opinion, `Math.random() < 0.1` is more intuitive to read as "10% chance of true" than `Math.random() >= 0.9`. I guess that's being pretty picky though. Nice answer.

Comment: I modified the answer to use the `<=` operator instead of `>=` to make the answer more intuitive.

Comment: Isn't the answer now semantically wrong? As @Aaron Plocharczyk described, shouldn't the 0.5 belong to the probability of the upper half? 0.0 belongs to the lower half and 1.0 is not in the [0,1) range of `Math-random()`. So please change the `<=` to `<`.

Comment: @bjrne You are correct; the last person that edited this answer made that mistake. I went ahead and updated the answer to reflect your suggestion and veer away from `>=` in favor of `<`.

Comment: I like the thought process used in arriving at the solution

Comment: Doesn't seem trustworthy, got all trues on the first run.

Comment: this is how casinos set up their machines 80% to the house ;)

Answer (score 38):

If your project has [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) then you can:

```
_.sample([true, false])
```

Alternatively you can use your own sample function ([source](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/sample)):

```
const sample = arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
```

Answer (score 18):

For a more cryptographically secure value, you can use [`crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) in modern browsers.

#### Sample:

```js
var randomBool = (function() {
  var a = new Uint8Array(1);
  return function() {
    crypto.getRandomValues(a);
    return a[0] > 127;
  };
})();

var trues = 0;
var falses = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
  if (randomBool()) {
    trues++;
  }
  else {
    falses++;
  }
}
document.body.innerText = 'true: ' + trues + ', false: ' + falses;
```

Note that the `crypto` object is a DOM API, so it's not available in Node, but [there is a similar API for Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725596/use-window-crypto-in-nodejs-code).

Comment: `Math.random()` is notoriously un-random in many ways, great alternate suggestion

Comment: I'm just gonna add a small correction here, as I discovered after 50 000 000 runs that it generated on average 0.78% or so more zeroes:

return a[0] <= 127; (Else 127 is never included)

Comment: @AmundMidtskog Good call. I should have typed: `a[0] > 127`

Comment: By the way, you may usually want to generate a much larger number of samples than just 255. Rather, in order to reduce the noise in the data, something like 100,000 – or even tens of millions, as suggested in the other comment, if you want to see errors as small as 0.78%.

Answer (score 16):

```
!Math.round(Math.random());
```

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Please format this more helpfully (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and add some explanation. Code-only answers are not very much appreciated. Adding an explanation would help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service.

Comment: above comment is not helpful.

Comment: So simple!!! Perfect!!!

Answer (score 14):

Impressed a lot by [Kelvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756480/7212563) I would like to suggest a fairly similar but slightly enhanced solution.

```
var randomBoolean = Math.random() < 0.5;
```

This solution is a bit more obvious to read, because the number on the right-hand side of `<` tells you the probability of getting `true` rather than of getting `false`, which is more natural to comprehend. Also `<` is one symbol shorter than `>=`;

Comment: The answer I was referring to has been updated and now suggests using `<` as well

Answer (score 3):

## Potentialy faster solutions...

Bitwise operator approach i just thought of `Math.random() + .5 >> 0` or `~~(Math.random() + .5)`. Here is a [performance test](https://jsben.ch/1BDOG) to judge for yourself.

```
let randomBoolean = Math.random() + .5 >> 0;                 //chance of true
const randomBoolean = chance => Math.random() + chance >> 0; //chance of true
```

The bitwise operators is in this case essentially just the same as using `Math.trunc()` or `Math.floor()`, therefore this is also posible `Math.trunc(Math.random() + .5)`.

```
let randomBoolean = Math.trunc(Math.random() + .5);
const randomBoolean = chance => Math.trunc(Math.random() + chance);
```

### Other more common solutions

The more readable and common way to get random boolean is probably a comparative approach like  `Math.random() >= .5` from [Kelvin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756480/10456329) or `Math.random() < .5;` from [Arthur Khazbs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322877/10456329), they actualy output true & false, and not 1 & 0.

```
let randomBoolean = Math.random() >= .5;                 //chance of false
const randomBoolean = chance => Math.random() >= chance; //chance of false

let randomBoolean = Math.random()  < .5;                 //chance of true
const randomBoolean = chance => Math.random() < chance;  //chance of true
```

The only reason to use the `Math.round(Math.random())` approach is simplicity.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worth pointing out, but `(.49999999999999997 >= .5) != (.49999999999999997+ .5 >> 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I just need a "random" boolean for a teaching example or something. Depending on your use-case, this might be random enough.

```js
function flipCoin() {
  return Boolean(Date.now() % 2);
}

console.log( flipCoin() );
```

Answer (score 2):

My way :)

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 ) % 2 === 1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

let try most easy solutions

```js
 let status=Math.round(Math.random())
 console.log(status)
 if(status==1)
 {
 status=true
 }else{
 status=false
 }
 console.log(status)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is pointless and verbose to use an if/else when you are testing a boolean value. It is also  not recommended to use == when you know it is a number. Use === 
`let status = Math.round(Math.random()) === 1;` is much shorter, but not a better random than the excepted answer

Answer (score -1):

How about this one?

```
return Math.round((Math.random() * 1) + 0) === 0;
```

Comment: OP states that he already uses similar methods, no need to post this.

Comment: why do you multiply it by one?